# Create GridLayout With Rows of Equal Height

Tags: java, layout, eclipse-plugin, swt

I want to have a composite with some labels, and all the labels should have the same height, but they should be vertically centered.

So far I have the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);
    composite.setLayout(GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().numColumns(1).equalWidth(true).spacing(0, 0).create());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.WRAP);
        label.setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
        label.setText(i < 5 ? "small " + i : "a very big text for the row that is named " + i);
        label.setToolTipText(label.getText());
        label.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().align(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER).grab(true, true).create());
    }

    shell.setSize(100, 600);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the labels are vertically centered in their rows, but the ones which wrap take more space than the other ones.

If I add `hint(SWT.DEFAULT, 60)`  to the `GridData`, I can force the labels to have the same height, but then they won't be vertically centered anymore.

I could probably wrap all the labels in composites, set the height hint on the composite and center the labels, but let's see of there is another option first.

How do I create vertically centered rows of equal height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to uniformly arrange widgets which may be different sizes, I think a good option would be to place each `Label` into a `Composite`. That way each `Composite` can have the same size, and the `Label` will be centered within.

By adding a `ControlListener` to the parent `Composite`, you can check the size of each child `Composite`, then set the height hint of each child to be the height of the largest child:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);
    composite.setLayout(GridLayoutFactory.fillDefaults().numColumns(1).equalWidth(true).spacing(0, 0).create());

    final List<Composite> children = new ArrayList<Composite>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final Composite c = new Composite(composite, SWT.BORDER);
        c.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        final Label label = new Label(c, SWT.WRAP);
        label.setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
        label.setText(i < 5 ? "small " + i : "a very big text for the row that is named " + i);
        label.setToolTipText(label.getText());
        label.setLayoutData(GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().align(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER).grab(true, true).create());

        children.add(c);
    }

    composite.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void controlResized(final ControlEvent e) {
            int maxHeight = 0;
            for (final Composite c : children) {
                if (c.getClientArea().height > maxHeight) {
                    maxHeight = c.getClientArea().height;
                }
            }
            for (final Composite c : children) {
                ((GridData) c.getLayoutData()).heightHint = maxHeight;
            }
        }
    });

    shell.setSize(100, 600);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

And after resizing:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This seems to work just by coincidence. `Composite.getClientArea().y` is its y-coordinate, not its height. You need to either do `getClientArea().height` or `getSize().y`.

Comment: Also, for me, `getClientArea().height` and `getSize().y` are always 0.

Comment: @mapeters Good catch - that should definitely be `getClientArea().height`. I've updated the code, thank you! They `Rectangle` returned by `getClientArea()` is 0x0 until resized for the first time. Then it will be correctly computed, and if you throw a print statement in the `ControlListener` you'll see it changing.